# Выгруска заказов с 1С (Не удалось получить ответ сервера. Файл не отправлен)

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

До определенного времени заказы уходили, все работало хорошо, но потом пошло что-то не так.

> ```
> Выгружено товаров: 4 750
> Выгружено предложений: 4 750
> Выгрузка товаров успешно завершена
> Выгружено заказов: 127
> Отправка файла на сервер: Получен пустой ответ сервера.
> Не удалось получить ответ сервера. Файл не отправлен (C:\Users\user4\AppData\Local\Temp\v8_13C0_4e3.zip).
> Обмен не выполнен
> Обмен заказами завершен с ошибками!!!
> ```

При этом zip архив попадает в папку /upload/1c_exchange, zip распаковывается, xml лежит внутри папки.

Выполнил рекомендации что на сайте битрикса, да и что на форумах нашел....

1. Хоть и файл уходит, но выключил антивирус..
2. Увеличил `max_execution_time` до 6000, `memory_limit` до 1536M
3. Выставил такие параметры (Выполнил как команду php в админке, потом вообще прописал в init.php)

COption::SetOptionString("catalog", "DEFAULT_SKIP_SOURCE_CHECK", "Y");
COption::SetOptionString("sale", "secure_1c_exchange", "N");

Ничего не помогло, я не знаю что делать.

```
В 1c_order_exchange.log

[17:01:30] StartExchange:
[17:01:30] VersionSchema: 2.05
[17:01:30] StartExchange:
[17:01:30] VersionSchema: 2.05
```

И так много раз

Answer (score 1):

Возможно изменилась схема XML и 1С теперь не может разобрать файл. Стоит посмотреть код через отладку. Ну и можно сравнить новые файлы с теми, что приходили раньше, обратить внимание на имя схемы в файле (атрибут "xmlns" у корневого объекта, в самом начале файла).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<<Имя корневого объекта> xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/"(<- Это имя схемы)>
```

Если изменилось и 1С обрабатывает xml через фабрику XDTO, то нужно поменять имя схемы в коде.